# reducing process time while creating pdf in laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, wms, pos

Hello I'm working on a WMS project using laravel and I need to print a table (to pdf), this table consist form 3 tables (heavy process time ) each row in this table have an image that is converted to base64 to be printed in the pdf (also heavy process time)
this is taking sooooo much time to create the pdf
I've tried using: 1- Laravel queue job
2- datatable pdf (laravel package)
3- laravel snappy-pdf (laravel package)
4- Laravel Dump-pdf (laravel package)
**NONE** of them worked in reducing process time
please help me...
*note: i have so many products in the table*

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Have you tried a front end solution like jsPDF?

Comment: how many products in the table ? average image size ? Server CPU/RAM/disk (ssd/nvme), php 7.4 or less ? database version ?